# Does this snippet cause an infinite loop or other?

Tags: java, android

Only on old android devices (2.x) I've a crash caused by stackoverflow everytime I rotate emulator. If I comment "preferenze()" emulator does not crash but app does not keep new settings. Can this code create an infinite loop? Is a incorrect code? What should be to runs correctly? Thanks!

```
private boolean preferencesChanged;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    private void preferenze() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
        ListPreference = prefs.getString("listpref", "");
        numeronotifiche = prefs.getString("notify", "");
        Sound = prefs.getString("sound", "");
        barranotifiche = prefs.getBoolean("keep", false);
        natura = prefs.getBoolean("suoninaturasino", false);
        snatura = prefs.getString("suoninaturascelta", "");
        snaturaold = prefs.getString("snaturaoldvalue", "");

        if (snaturaold != snatura){
            stopService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));

        }

        SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, 0);

        Editor editor10 = prefs2.edit();
        editor10.putString("snaturaoldvalue", snatura);
        editor10.commit();

        // suoni attivati (o no)

        if (natura){
            startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
        }
        else {
            stopService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
        }

        if (barranotifiche){
            showNotification();
        }
            else {
                cancelNotification();
            }

        GestioneAllarme alarm = new GestioneAllarme();
        if (CheckboxPreference){
            if (numeronotifiche.equals("3")){
            alarm.CancelAlarm(this);
            alarm.SetAlarm3(this);
        }
            else if (numeronotifiche.equals("1")){
                alarm.CancelAlarm(this);
                alarm.SetAlarm1(this);
            }
            else if (numeronotifiche.equals("2")){
                alarm.CancelAlarm(this);
                alarm.SetAlarm2(this);
            }
            else {
//              
            }
        }
        else {
//            
            GestioneAllarme alarm2 = new GestioneAllarme();
            alarm2.CancelAlarm(this);
            }   

//        
        if (Sound.equals("")){
            Sound = "2";
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("sound", "2");
            editor.commit();
        }


        if (ListPreference.equals("")){
            ListPreference = "1500";

          Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putString("listpref", "1500");
          editor.putInt("indexfade", 1500);
          editor.commit();

        }

        if (numeronotifiche.equals("")){
            numeronotifiche = "2";
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putString("numeronotifiche", "2");
              editor.commit();
        }


        fade = Integer.parseInt(ListPreference);
        notify = Integer.parseInt(numeronotifiche);

        if (fade == 500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme1;
            fadein = R.anim.fadein500;
            fadeout = R.anim.fadeout500;
        }
        else if (fade == 1000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme2;
            fadein = R.anim.fadein1000;
            fadeout = R.anim.fadeout1000;
        }
        else if (fade == 1500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme3;
            fadein = R.anim.fadein1500;
            fadeout = R.anim.fadeout1500;
        }
        else if (fade == 2000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme4;
            fadein = R.anim.fadein2000;
            fadeout = R.anim.fadeout2000;


@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                    preferencesChanged = true;
                }            
        };
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();


        if(preferencesChanged){
            //Update the app
            preferenze();
        }
    }


public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {
```

Comment: just edited my answer with a possible solution to avoid infinite loop and keeping the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that as soon as `preferenze()` always modify the shared preferences you will have an infinite loop.

Since you didn't post the complete code it's difficult to say. But I guess that your code is such that it always modify prefs only on android 2.x

you can try something like this to avoid infinite loop.

```
private boolean isPreferenzeRunning = false;
...
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {       
            if(!isPreferenzeRunning)preferenze();
          }
   };
...
private void preferenze()
    isPreferenzeRunning = true;
    try{
       ...
    }finally{isPreferenzeRunning = false;}       
}
```

Comment: seems your code runs, now I'll stress emulator to better tests. For now very thanks!

Comment: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" after many rotates

Answer (score 1):

> // here several if/if else to change value

Those sentences probably change the Shared Preferences, that in turn will fire your listener, which in turn will call `preferenze`, ..., and so on. If this continues for ever, a S.O will be thrown. Now depending on the conditions it could happen that the `preferenze` method only reads but does not modify anything. In this case the loop will end.

And about the error being observed in 2.X devices only, it could be due to 4.x devices being more recent and probably having more RAM memory.

---

UPDATE:
The code is still incomplete. Looks like there are two activities: the one you posted first and the new one. I guess (that's all I can do with the code you posted) you have a `PreferenceActivity` to show the settings and allow the user to change them, and the listener is there to update other parts of the application according to the new settings. The problem is that when the listener is called, it itself modifies the settings, and this in turn will call the listener again, which will modify the preferences again, and so on. This will throw an SOException once the heap runs out of memory.

A way of rearranging the code to solve this would be:

1. Register the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your activity's `onResume` instead of `onCreate`, and deregister it in the `onPause` method (calling `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`). Deregistering is very important because we don't want to listen for changes once the user leaves the screen, or the activity is recreated by the system (for instance when the device rotates):

   ```
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           //We have removed the listener registration from here
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();

           SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
           listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
               public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String   listpref) {       
                   //I'll show what to do here in point 2.
               }
           };
           sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPause() {
           super.onPause();

           SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
           sp.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
       }
   ```
2. With your current code, each time the user changes a single setting, the `preferenze` method is called to update the app. So if it changes 5 fields, the method is called 5 times. What we could do now is to check for changes just once. I assume you don't care how many fields the user has changed, since all you need is to know if there are changes or not. So in the listener, instead of calling `preferenze`, you could set a boolean flag to true:

   ```
       public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
           preferencesChanged = true;
       }
   ```
3. Ok, so now we have a way of telling whether the settings have changed or not. When the user is done and the activity is about to be closed, the methods `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroy` will be called in this order. You can use one of these methods to check the boolean flag and only if there are changes, update the app. This way, if the user changes 1, 3 or 20 fields, we will update the app just once at the end. You can do this in any of the 3 thethods, but it's very important to do this AFTER deregistering the listener (`onPause`), or else you'll run into problems again. Example:

   ```
       protected void onStop(){
           super.onStop();
           ...

           if(preferencesChanged){
               //Update the app
               preferenze();
           }
       }
   ```

You might need to change some things but overall you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The listener "register" new preferences of app. Now, I can resolve this problem? Open app, rotate emulator... crashes.

Comment: Thanks! How check if listpref is different from old value?

Comment: Forget that. I stated it wrong. Screen rotation per se don't fire a SharedPreferences change. What happens is that the rotation recreates your activity. Check your activity lifecycle methods (onPause, onStop, onDestroy) you are probably modifying the prefs there too.

Comment: Yep. I check some values and store it to shared preferences. Is this a problem? why? if I comment "preferenze()" emulator does not crash.

Comment: Those changes are firing the listener. So you could unregister the listener when your old activity is being destroyed, and BEFORE you make the final modifications to the prefs. That way the changes made in `onPause`, `onStop`, etc, wont fire the listener. That would solve the rotation case, but any other pref change will still fire the loop.

Comment: I've something like this int a = savedInstanceState.getInt("arraystart"); int b = savedInstanceState.getInt("arrayend");

Comment: is too hard for me... can you write an example code to do this?

Comment: The problem is that we don't have enough code to help you. I'd suggest you to post all the lines of your activity where you are using `SharedPreferences`. Also you could elaborate a bit more on why are you using the listener and what kind of changes do you want to process and which ones not.

Comment: thanks. If I remove prefs3.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); does listener run for keep preferences?

Comment: No, if you don't register the listener it will never run.

Comment: I read your code again. Now it seems clear that your code is recursive in nature: change in preferences -> listener -> preferenze -> change in preferences -> ... So a change in preferences made somewhere in your code will produce the error sooner or later. You should redesign your code to break this vicious cycle. You could start thinking why do you need to call `preferenze` in the listener.

Comment: mhmhm... when I change options on my app (notifications, fade or others) listener update options. If I not call preferenze() in listener, how can I update options?

Comment: I guess this activity shows the current state of the options, isn't it?

Comment: ! I'm amazed about your answer! Very very thanks! Until point 1 I understand. Where I put:  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {preferencesChanged = true; to onCreate() method? Thanks again!

Comment: You can put that in the line where you are instantiating the listener. I've done this in the `onResume` method as you can see in point 1 (The line that says "//I'll show what to do here in point 2.").

Comment: ok...it's very hard to me. What I should put to onCreate()? be patience. thanks.

Comment: I updated the code with your corrections, so you can understand if it's correct. thanks again.

Comment: I'd revert it to its previous value. Think that people with similar problems will come to your question, and if you modify the code like that neither the question nor the answers will make sense any longer. About how to best fix your code, i'm a bit busy right now so i'm afraid the rest is up to you :)

Comment: sorry if I ask you again your help. I tried for many many hours but I can't resolve this problem :-( When you've time, can you help me please? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That code wouldn't even compile.

The code in `preferenze()` will return the preference values (boolean, String, int, etc), not the Preference objects. By changing the values in that method, you will also cause a `StackOverflowError`.

What is the need for a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`?

Comment: the code is incomplete, since declaration of fields : CheckboxPreference, ListPreference, numeronotifiche, ... are missing.